# Edittext list editing

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext, barcode-scanner

In my app there's a large EditText field that contains barcodes separated by "\n". Barcodes can be added to this EditText field either programmatically(in onActivityResult returning from a scanning Activity) or manually.

Random example:

```
010566510415
40541651654556
561516551588
0043211652
003789453
```

I need each of these barcodes to be saved locally with their barcode type.

Random example:

```
012315612323 - Code128 (scanned)
561516551588 - Custom (manually inputted)
0123156124xx - Code128_Custom (scanned, then edited by user!!)
```

The scanning library I use identifies the barcode types on scan, so I have an ArrayList of objects that saves the scanned barcodes with their respective barcode type.

```
public class BarcodeObject
    {
        private int _position = -1;
        private String _barcode = "";
        private String _barcodeType = "";
    }
```

The problem I'm having is keeping the `ArrayList<BarcodeObject>` in sync with the editText, when the user manually edits a barcode.

Do you have any ideas as how I should accomplish this?

**Edit 1 :** Thank you for your answers. One issue is that I don't know what barcode the user is modifying. I managed to solve it by using `numbersList.getSelectionStart();` to find out where the cursor is and then look for the nearest "\n" so as to identify the correct barcode(bcs all barcodes are between "\n"). But what happens if the user click selects more than one barcodes and changes them. I just don't know how to keep them in sync.

Comment: Keep TextWatcher on your edittext and try to search with existing arraylist if something is changed by user

Answer (score 0):

you can update the array list based of index, example :

```
private ArrayList<BarcodeObject> barcodes = new ArrayList<Object>();
barcodes.set(#indexposition#, #BarcodeObject#);
```

and add getter and setter in your BarcodeObject class, for update the object;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an EditText only and you want to save the data after the user stop typing...

You have to extend the class with TextWatcher and override **afterTextChanged()**,**beforeTextChanged()**, **onTextChanged()**.
You have to write your desired logic in afterTextChanged() method to achieve functionality needed by you.

That means, in your afterTextChanged(), you can write the following code and it will work well..

```
bcodes.set(#position#, #Barcode-Object#);
```

Assuming you have already initilized bcodes...

```
private ArrayList<BarcodeObject> bcodes = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!